# How to discretize linear time-varying dynamic system?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory

I'm working on a linear time-varying system and need to discretize the system like:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 &v(t) &0\\
0& 0    &v(t)\\
0& 0  &0\\
\end{bmatrix}}^{A^C}x+\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}}^{B^c}u
\end{equation}

with $v(t)=v_{tk}+a_{tk}(t-tk)+\frac{1}{2}j_{tk}(t-tk)^2$, $j_{tk}$ ist the constant during $t\in[tk,tk+1]$

I have to find the $A^{D}$ and $B^{D}$, but I don't know how to handle with that. The normal solution is:
\begin{equation}
    {A}_d={\phi}_k(T_s),  
   {B}_d=\int_{0}^{T_s}{\phi}_k(\tau){B}_cd\tau\\
\end{equation}
$\phi_k$=I+$A_c$t+$\frac{1}{2!}A_{c}^2t^2+...$;
but I'm not sure it's going to be work and how to discretize the LTI problem. Pls help ..

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" solution is only for time-invariant systems (as you said), but the idea is the same. So, find the solution at time $t+T$ as
$$\begin{align}
x(t+T) &= \phi(t+T,t_0) x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t+T} \phi(t+T,\tau) B(\tau) u(\tau) d\tau \\
&= \phi(t+T,t) \phi(t,t_0) x(t_0) + \phi(t+T,t) \int_{t_0}^{t} \phi(t,\tau) B(\tau) u(\tau) d\tau + \int_{t}^{t+T} \phi(t+T,\tau) B(\tau) u(\tau) d\tau \\
&= \phi(t+T,t) x(t) + \int_{t}^{t+T} \phi(t+T,\tau) B(\tau) u(\tau) d\tau
\end{align}$$
Assuming Zero-Order Hold and since $B$ is time invariant, we can rewrite these as
$$x_{k+1} = A_k x_k + B_k u_k$$
where
$$A_k := \phi(t_k+T,t_k) ~~ \text{and} ~~ B_k := \left( \int_{t_k}^{t_k+T} \phi(t_k+T, \tau) d\tau \right) B$$
In general, we cannot go further than that, but in your specific case you can obtain $\phi(\cdot)$ explicitly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!